# Insert data Into MS Access database table using SQL

Tags: ms-access, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data into a table in my MS Access database.

When doing so MS Access informs me that I am about to append 1 row.

When I return to the table to check the data I still have a blank table.

If I click on the Filters on the table I can see my data as options but they will not show up in the actual table.

```
INSERT INTO PATIENTS (PatID, FirstName, LastName, Age, Phone, InsuranceCompany)
VALUES (00000090, 'Luke', 'Howell', 42, 7709999785, 'Blue Cross Blue Shield' );
```

Comment: are you sure you are looking against the same table?

Comment: Yes i am looking at the correct table @Rahul

Comment: It is a table in Ms Access @HansUp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I Figured It Out.

I Was Not In The "Datasheet View"

Answer (score 1):

When the `INSERT` runs without error, but also without actually adding a row to the table, that could be the result of a key violation.  However Access won't notify you if you're using `DoCmd.RunSQL` to execute the statement.  In other situations, a notice could be suppressed if you have turned `SetWarnings` off.

Run your `INSERT` with the `DAO.Database.Execute` method and its *dbFailOnError* option.  Also make sure `SetWarnings` is on ...

```vb
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO PATIENTS (PatID, FirstName, LastName, Age, Phone, InsuranceCompany) " & _
    "VALUES (00000090, 'Luke', 'Howell', 42, 7709999785, 'Blue Cross Blue Shield' );"
Debug.Print strInsert '<- view this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: I am kind of not understanding how to input this code into MS Access as it gives me a error of "Invalid SQL Statement Expected"